# avoid duplicate products in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I have faced a problem in laravel , that i have products filter by category and subcategory but the problem i have many product have same partNumber .
what i need is to get just one product with that partNumber

```php
$products = Product::all();
$productIds = $products->unique('product_part_number')->pluck('id');
                          
$product =  $product->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

return view('livewire.multi-report', [
    'products' => $product,
]);
```

This is the code when i use collection i can not use paginate , **product** variable is declarated up with filters

any help :)

when i use unique with collection to filter by

```
product_part_number
```

I can not use pagination

Comment: Have you looked into ->groupBy('product_part_number') ? It will pick the first record it comes across.

Comment: Like that  $product->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('product_part_number')->paginate(10)